# Even a synchronized method generates same UUID

Tags: java, multithreading, uuid

I know a lot of people will not believe this but I am currently facing an issue where I am getting a same UUID even though the method generating it is synchronized.

```
private synchronized String generateUUID() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
 }
```

Now my application stores records in the database (in parallel, multi-threaded) and you can consider this UUID as part of the unique key. I am expecting this method to return me an actual unique generated string before i persist the record even if the time difference between threads is 1 ns.

Is there someway I can guarantee the generation of this unique ID to be actually unique.

Comment: I'm sure this works fine in Java (whatever version you're using). The error must be in the code you're not showing. If you look at the source code of UUID, it's guaranteed that the id will be different even when called concurrently.

Comment: Can you show us the context in which this question is asked?

Comment: maybe you need to make the method `static` if you have several instances of the class containing this method.

Comment: Does the length of the UUID matter?

Comment: Yeah, I'd probably look upstream for an underlying cause.

Comment: It would seem that [there used to be a bug](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6611830) with how randomUUIDs were generated, however that was supposedly fixed in Java 7, and seems that the issue was only for non-synchronized uses.

Comment: @Augusto It is a simple persist operation, I can post it but it wont give you any useful information. And it does not work for sure because when I run the debugger on the code it works as I stop the execution for each thread.

Comment: @JoseMartinez No it does not.

Comment: @Dannnno 7 I am on java 6 but still have it synchronized. So I don't know whats happening.

Comment: [Ideone doesn't seem to like this either](https://ideone.com/WHHIDq).

Comment: @NickDiv Without more code, we really cannot help you.  The only answer we can give you is that you are doing something wrong in the code you haven't posted.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer:  This should not be happening and this solution is just a hack to get you going forward until you solve the underlying problem.

```
AtomicInteger hackDigit = new AtomicInteger(0);

private synchronized String generateUUID() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString() + hackDigit.getAndIncrement();
}
```

EDIT:  By the way this is a good way to help you troubleshoot cause you can verify the method is getting called multiple times.

Comment: I have already used this hacky fix because it was breaking my system. And yes the method does get called as many times as the records to be persisted. But I just dont understand how can the method generate same UUID's specially a synchronized one.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with the following code with jdk1.7.0_76 and jdk1.6.0_75:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    int numThreads = 30;

    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);
    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
        es.execute(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    latch.await();
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + ":  UUID = " + generateUUID());
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
            }
        });
    }
    latch.countDown();
    es.shutdown();
}

private static synchronized String generateUUID() {
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}
```

And I got the following output:

```
38:  UUID = 5fd7d56a-42a9-4edc-a114-ccf86bcf1e20
37:  UUID = be1815fd-3bd4-4761-bcf7-4ad303ee585a
23:  UUID = 80c1920e-566a-44d7-993c-4ce0807e0aef
22:  UUID = caba14c7-77fc-4ed5-9063-5c41d6ee43dc
21:  UUID = a542a0e9-55c3-4a95-8614-86dcb052d337
24:  UUID = abdb5275-a3c3-4114-aa4e-088d978d4ba1
25:  UUID = f0ddaa6d-9129-4344-bcf7-499663203270
26:  UUID = b997ee94-555a-4a26-9c6c-8415ff301b18
20:  UUID = d9f3b912-251b-45b6-b15b-22f6b1c44d13
27:  UUID = 54c491c0-e2a6-4eda-988f-d468e7c089d9
28:  UUID = 7b94ee4e-e450-4d35-ad65-28b0ae394c12
29:  UUID = 4cea2da0-9815-418c-b6d8-98e40d382ca5
30:  UUID = 6025824c-2f8c-4d90-9631-2e178c2679cc
31:  UUID = e743664c-df13-4f56-9f4c-f3e47729d9a7
15:  UUID = 35f1a715-c5c5-4db1-9ac4-a8ecd33f32d2
32:  UUID = e6371c34-b6fb-4f83-955d-0a9cc2b464db
33:  UUID = 8e26bd45-2e0a-47b2-b8ec-4e76aae18174
14:  UUID = 0b5b1c58-71df-4351-9275-5f192f485700
13:  UUID = 93bb6308-ca15-4c82-b2e1-10f17e41597a
34:  UUID = a64770ae-8828-446c-af7a-a327d097871f
11:  UUID = e45fef37-ab5d-42c4-b786-71f30aee3fa4
10:  UUID = 1d6938ce-27db-4cad-a191-21cf008671cc
9:  UUID = 2fa7e5c6-ac7c-4ce8-98fa-b298013aaf52
35:  UUID = ffda2492-1c43-42ff-baf4-0a122e67e8ac
36:  UUID = 9e630172-e90a-48f1-8e13-c57c119f7ede
12:  UUID = 9e378e06-d502-4ce7-94ad-5cc1431801cd
16:  UUID = bb17f0da-7672-4009-8fad-51050aa6bb69
17:  UUID = c0dec6ab-324b-466c-a69f-4c667c240dd4
18:  UUID = 3398dd05-1020-4df4-b365-73083950a5a4
19:  UUID = 84766676-d7f5-4fae-9765-367bbf4efebe
```

Which JDK are you using?  Can you try this code with your JDK?  Also, I tested it with and without synchronized.  Also, I made my static, but can test it without static.

Comment: will be more helpful if we explain what did we achieve in this solution and how. Thanks

Comment: That UUID is unique even when not synchronized. @ParamvirSinghKarwal